# Обновление данных переданных в адаптер RecyclerView из фрагмента или изменение ArrayList и всех ссылок на него

Tags: java, android, ооп, recyclerview

**Дано:**

Фрагмент запускает скачивание данных, хранит их в своём поле и передаёт ссылку на это поле через конструктор.

**Проблема:**

При обновлении данных полю фрагмента присваиваются новые данные. Но при этом в одном из двух вариантов данные в адаптере не изменяются.

*Код из класса фрагмента:*

```
//Изначально данные отображаю так:
recycler.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(artsList));
//после прихода новых - заменяю данные во фрагменте
//И вот тут становится непонятно.

//если так - то данные в адаптере не изменятся
//artsList = new ArrayList<>(list);
//А вот так данные в адаптере изменяются.
artsList.clear();
artsList.addAll(list);
```

**Вопрос:**

Почему так происходит?.. Почему для изменения ссылок на экземпляр списка надо вызвать `clear();` и `addAll(list);`, а повторная инициализация не отражается на ссылках на объект?

Comment: эээ, типа вы делаете `new Адаптер(artsList)`, а потом artsList = new ArrayList<>(), и удивляетесь, почему внутри адаптера новый список не виден?

Comment: @zRrr, типа того... если `artsList = new ArrayList<>()`, то список в адаптере не меняется. Если `artsList.clear();` и `artsList.addAll(list);` - то в адаптере меняется. Я чую, что не понимаю каких-то базовых вещей(

Comment: `Почему для изменения ссылок на экземпляр списка надо вызвать clear(); и addAll(list);` - а разве мы этим действием меняете ссылку? мне почему то казалось что ссылка при таком действии остается прежней.

Comment: конструктор копирует ссылку на список из параметра в поле адаптера. когда вы делаете `artsList = new ArrayList()`, создается новый список и ссылка на него кладется в `artsList` (а в поле адаптера все еще лежит ссылка на старый список). Поэтому адаптер вообще не в курсе про новый список и новое значение переменной `artsList`.

Comment: @ermak0ff, ну, в случае `artsList = new ArrayList<>()` я полагал, что и в адаптере, в коий передан `artsList` тоже станет `new ArrayList<>()`. Т.е. я присвоил новое значение переменной `artsList` и это отразится на всех ссылках на неё... Однако отражаются только изменения над объектом, а не замена объекта. Я запутался(

Comment: стоп, `artsList` - это поле адаптера, или просто какая-то локальная переменная?

Comment: @zRrr, `artsList`- поле фрагмента. Оно передаётся в адаптер и присваивается полю адаптера.

Comment: `Я запутался(` щас практически с такой же темой сижу...вот когда добавляется еще и возможность фильтрации, вот тогда вообще жесть что творится)))над еще и origin копию создавать%)

Comment: представьте, что у вас не объекты, а инты. Вы делаете `фрагмент.artsClear = 5; адаптер.поле = фрагмент.artsClear; фрагмент.artsClear = 7;`. В поле адаптера будет все еще 5.

Comment: как мне кажется, если: 1)`artsList = new ArrayList<>(list);` - Вы у поля изменили ссылку, в следствии чего потеряли ссылку на лист который в адаптере...2) `artsList.clear();artsList.addAll(list);` ссылка при данном действии не изменилась, юзаем нотифай, все гуд)

Comment: @zRrr, с `int` - то понятно, пробовал когда-то) Но это ж примитив... А тут - объекты, ссылки... Если я в список данные добавлю `add()`  - то они и во фрагменте добавятся и в адаптере.

Comment: @ermak0ff, звучит логично, но я почему-то ожидал, что изменения значения поля также отразится и на всех полях которым было присвоено значение этого поля(

Comment: `но я почему-то ожидал, что изменения значения поля также отразится и на всех полях которым было присвоено значение этого поля` ну так так и есть...если вы сделаете add() к полю,а потом нотифай то все обновиться же

Comment: @ermak0ff, я под значением имею в виду объект, на коий `artsList` ссылается... Я думал, что если я artsList-у присвою новый объект, то он присвоится и полю адаптера... А то что, add добавит всюду и отобразится - это-то понятно)

Comment: даа, было бы круто если бы так было, но увы и ах, довольствуемся тем что имеем)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смотрите. Ссылка в Java (а также в C#) есть отдельная от самого объекта штука. Когда вы создаёте объект (в конечном итоге при помощи `new`), объект как бы висит в воздухе, а ссылка — лишь «почтовый адрес» этого объекта. Это является аналогом *указателя на объект* в языках наподобие C++.

Если вы меняете поле объекта по ссылке на него, то происходит *разыменование* ссылки: из адреса объекта достаётся сам объект, и на нём выполняется действие.

Но когда вы присваиваете ссылке «почтовый адрес» другого объекта, то только вы теряете адрес старого объекта. Те, у кого всё ещё остались ссылки на старый объект, до сих пор могут им пользоваться.

Почему так сделано? Во-первых, это легко заимплементировать, ссылки на объекты «под капотом» ведут себя как адреса. Во-вторых, это привычная программистам на C и C++ семантика. И в-третьих, представьте себе, что любой, у кого есть ссылка на объект, при переприсвоении ссылки «испортит» все остальные ссылки. Тогда даже вот такой код:

```
Object temp = o1;
o1 = o2;
o2 = temp;
```

не будет работать ожидаемым образом. Поскольку после присвоения `o1 = o2` ссылка `temp` тоже станет указывать на `o2`! Таким образом, у вас исчезнет понятие локальной переменной: любая переменная будет навсегда привязана к объекту, которым она была инициализирована.

---

То, чего вы хотите — это паттерн Flyweight.

Вкратце: вы пользуетесь не объектом, а контейнером: простым классом с одним публичным полем, содержащим нужный объект. Вы даёте все ссылку на контейнер, а если вам нужно поменять содержимое, подменяете объект в контейнере.

Таким образом, все, кто имеет ссылку на контейнер, увидят новый объект.

Comment: Спасибо, но я несколько о другом спрашивал, а именно: почему в Java при замене экземпляра, на коий ссылается одна переменная он же не присваивается всем остальным ссылкам, кои раньше ссылались на содержимое переменной. Ответ в духе - "так уж Java задумывалась"/"так уж ООП работает" не принимаются)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: окей, сейчас допишу.

Comment: Эх, вроде даже что-то понял) Это один и тех моментов, когда я замечаю отсутствие профильного образования... Спасибо!

Comment: @ЮрийСПб: Пожалуйста!