# Не обновляется RecyclerView после вызова notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview

Есть обработчик EditText

```
private fun filterEdit(editText: EditText, map: MutableMap<String, Chat>){
        editText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                val newMap = list.filter{ it.key.contains(s,true) }
                adapter?.updateList(newMap)
                Log.i("Edit","${newMap} ${adapter?.itemCount}")
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
        })
    }
```

При старте (может это играет какую-то роль) список имеет всего 1 элемент, как только я ввожу в EditText строку которую не пропускает фильтр. newMap выводит в логе что список пустой, замет я передаю его в адаптер

```
   fun updateList(newMap: Map<String, Chat>){
        map = newMap
        setUserId = map.keys
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
```

map в адаптере - это список от которого зависит длина списка и что в нем будет, и в логе EditText он возвращает 0, но список все равно не обновляется, что не так??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут дело в ссылках на разные экземпляры контейнера с данными ([подробное объяснение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/469202/17609)) Простым фиксом будет замена значения по ссылке на изменение уже имеющегося значения:

Вместо:

> map = newMap

напишите:

```
map.clear()
map.putAll(newMap)
```